# How to evaluate the extreme of this double integral

Tags: integration

Can someone help me to find integration extremes of this integral
$\iint_c (2xy-x)dxdy$

where $c = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2  | y<-x^2+1,y>x^2-1\}$.
I have computed $x$ = $\sqrt{y-1}$ and $x$ = $-\sqrt{y-1}$
can someone make me clear this integral please i do not know if i have nailed it

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). I assume ER meant $\in\mathbb{R}$ (`\in\mathbb{R}`).

Comment: Are you sure that the inequalities defining $c$ are $y<-x^2+1$ and $y>x^2+1$?

Comment: I Suppose that one of the two inequalities is $y>x^2-1$

Comment: yes you are right i edited the post  I wrote it down wrong

Comment: What are you struggling with? The bounds of $y$ is given and all you need to do is to find the bounds of $x$ by finding the intersection of both curves. In any case the answer will be zero as both terms have $x$ ($x$ is odd function) and the region has symmetry about y-axis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After your edit, the problem is clear.

Simply evaluate

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left[\int_{x^2-1}^{1-x^2}(2xy-x)dy   \right]dx$$

Comment: could you  explain the bounds for the x, please?

Comment: If you did a drawing of your $c$ you will realize that the integtation region is the intersection of 2 parabolas. By the way did you forget to accept my answer?

Comment: thank you very much I have just noticed that I have not accept your answer  just done

Comment: just to be sure  at the end the result of this double integral is 0                                                        Is that correct?